# Count down timer whenever file is opened

Tags: org-mode, time-date, org-clock

C-C C-x ; can start count down timer. But I want to start the timer whenever I open any org file. I want to set it default for 10 minute. Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the function to `org-mode-hook`?

If you haven't tried it yet, what I would recommend is to create a
function `my-org-mode-hook-function` which evaluates
`(org-timer-set-timer 10)`. Then add to your `.emacs` file the expression
`(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook-function)`.

Comment: How do you create a hook.? Kindly explain

Comment: You don't create any hook. `org-mode-hook` is a pre-existing emacs variable, meant to contain a list of functions to be evaluated when starting `org-mode`.

Comment: Can you teach me how you create a function my-org-mode-hook-function which evaluates (org-timer-set-timer 10. Kinldy oblige

Comment: `(defun my-org-mode-hook-function () (org-timer-set-timer 10))`

Comment: gets error. End of file during parsing

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic solution. Can this timer reset every time I open an org file and can it show a pop up at the end of 10 minute