# Count down timer and org

Tags: org-mode, idle-timer, timers, date-to-time

[count down timer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38121/count-down-timer-whenever-file-is-opened/38125#comment60041_38125) This code starts a count down timer every time org file is opened , but asks for a permission to reset timer every time . Can it be automated, meaning it should start counting as soon as org file is opened. 
Second, it should show a pop up when time is up. Can you please help

Comment: for the popup part: if you are on linux, you can use `notify-send`. also i'm curious: why u need a timer for org-files?

Comment: To limit the interaction time so that I can follow the schedule. I am on windows

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the pop up but, in place of that, I suggest that you use a bell sound.

You should have a ***wav*** sound file for this and you could use a bell sound like [org-pomodoro](https://github.com/lolownia/org-pomodoro)'s.

From `C-h f org-timer-set-timer` (org-timer-set-timer function help):

> With two ‘C-u’ prefix arguments, use ‘org-timer-default-timer’ without
>   prompting the user for a duration and automatically replace any
>   running timer.

To emulate `C-u`:

`(let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))  ... )` emulates `C-u`

`(let ((current-prefix-arg '(16)))  ... )` emulates `C-u C-u`

Putting the following in your init file should do the trick:

```el
(setq org-clock-sound "/path/to/sound.wav") ; set `org-clock-sound'
;; set default org-timer to 10 minutes (for X minutes and Y seconds, use "X:Y")
(setq org-timer-default-timer "10")
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (let ((current-prefix-arg '(16)))
              (call-interactively 'org-timer-set-timer))))
```

Don't forget to change `"/path/to/sound.wav"` to the real path.